# Why doesn't the default mapkit annotation not render on the map in the iOS simulator

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit

I am using `MKAnnotation` protocol to help display the default marker annotation on my iOS simulator map but I don't see it rendered.

Here is my `DriverAnnotation` class that I created;

```
class DriverAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var uid: String

    init(uid: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.uid = uid
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}
```

and here is the code that uses it and should display the marker annotation on the map;

```
    func fetchDrivers() {
        guard let location = locationManager?.location else { return }
        Service.shared.fetchDrivers(location: location) { (driver) in
            guard let coordinate = driver.location?.coordinate else { return }
            let annotation = DriverAnnotation(uid: driver.uid, coordinate: coordinate)
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }

    }
```

So why doesn't the annotation render on the iOS simulator map? All I get is the slowly blinking blue dot of the current location.

[image: map annotation missing]

Comment: @Rob, yes both ```coordinate``` and the ```uid``` both print out as expected. Could it be because MapKit has changed since this used to work?

Comment: @Rob thanks I will see if I can post a reproducible example of the problem as you request.

Comment: @Rob I have tested your code at the above link but I am not seeing the blinking blue dot of the user's current location - just the annotation marker.

Comment: @Rob ok after setting the plist privacy entries I can now see the user's location (Apple) and the annotation. However I am still not seeing the annotation in my own code when I add the ```mapView.register(MKMarkerAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)``` code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214358/discussion-between-rob-and-sjlearmonth).

Answer (score 0):

The `displayPriority` of `MKMarkerAnnotationView` defaults to `.defaultLow` (although [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkannotationview/2867298-displaypriority) for `MKAnnotationView`’s `displayPriority` suggests it should default to `.required`).

So you want a `MKMarkerAnnotationView` that is `.required`, then you want to declare an annotation view class, that sets it to `.required`:

```swift
class RequiredMarkerAnnotationView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        displayPriority = .required
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        didSet {
            displayPriority = .required
        }
    }
}
```

And

```swift
mapView.register(RequiredMarkerAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
```